# Add querystring to "asp-page" link in CORE razor pages

Tags: razor-pages

In CORE razor pages

```
<a asp-page="View" asp-route-ID="@item.ID" >View</a>
```

this creates a link to a page using a route to pass the ID and generates the following HTML

```
<a href="view/666">View</a>
```

I want to add the contents of the querystring to this link so the generated HTML looks like

```
<a href="view/666/?s=smith">View</a>
```

`@Request.QueryString` gets the entire querystring e.g. `"?s=smith"` but I can't find the way to add it to the end.

Any ideas.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me (from https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/anchor-tag-helper):

```
<a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register" asp-route-view="personal">Text</a>
```

This routes you to: Identity/Account/Register?view=personal.

In "asp-route-**view**", the view can be anythin you need:

```
<a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register" asp-route-disco="party">Text</a>
```

routes you to Identity/Account/Register?disco=party.

Answer (score 2):

Example Url :
https://localhost:44313/dados_pessoais?userid=1

Use: asp-route-**youproperty**="value"

Get user data sample

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/dados_pessoais" asp-route-userid="1">Dados Pessoais</a>
```

c#

```
public void OnGet(int userid)
{
    var usuario = Usuarios.Where(u => u.Id == userid).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: That doesn't take the contents of the querystring and let me add it in it's entirety, that's just the standard way to add route values.

Comment: I agree that it can be the route pattern, but that way I can capture the content of the querystring userid = xpto and use it, sorry if it was not useful.

Answer (score -1):

The asp router tag helpers will ensure the target page matches the format specified but assuming it does you can do something like the following:

```
<a asp-page="View" asp-route-ID="@item.ID" asp-route-s="@Request.Query["s"].ToString()">View</a>
```

The Request Query property can be used to access individual querystring parameters by name.